# initialise list of many empty lists (that are not copies)

Tags: python

```
>>> f = [[]] * 3
[[], [], []]
>>> f[0].append(1)
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

I think `[[]] * x` creates a list of `x` lists, but each inner list is the same object so changing one inner list changes all the others.

How can I quickly initialise a list of lists, but have each inner list be unique?

I want

```
>>> f = something
[[], [], []]
>>> f[0].append(1)
[[1], [], []]
```

Comment: `[[] for _ in range(3)]`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
f = [[] for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: @minseong, is there a difference in behavior between `for x` and `for _` or it is a notification that name wont be used?

Comment: traditionally `_` is a throwaway variable. Means its value won't be used. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47599668/3310334